# How can I count same words from sentences?

Tags: python, string, count, cpu-word

I want to ask how to count the same words from sentences(In Python).

As for an example, from a sentence like:
"What a wonderful day. Birds are singing, children are laughing."

What I want to extract is:
['what':1, 'a':1, 'wonderful':1, 'dat':1, 'birds':1, 'are':2, 'singing':1, 'children':1, 'laughing':1]

I have made here:

```
sent = "What a wonderful day. Birds are singing, children are laughing."
b = set([word.lower() for word in a])
c = list(b)
```

If this code isn't appropriate for the job, please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `collections.Counter` + `string.strip` to strip punctuations:

```
from collections import Counter
import string

sent = "What a wonderful day. Birds are singing, children are laughing."

c = Counter([x.strip(string.punctuation) for x in sent.split()])
print(c)

# Counter({'are': 2, 'What': 1, 'a': 1, 'wonderful': 1, 'day': 1, 'Birds': 1, 'singing': 1, 'children': 1, 'laughing': 1})
```

If you want this to be case insensitive, transform to lowercase before finding the count, like below:

```
s = sent.lower().translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
```

Comment: Better than using `.lower()` for case insensivity is to use `.casefold()` as it handles internationalizion better.

Comment: @JohanL While it's true, this has to be a lot considered on what the data actually is. If it's plain English (no unicodes), using `lower()` is the cleanest and avoids lookups.

Comment: I disagree when it comes to "clean". The `.casefold()` function is added for this particular reason and as such I think the default should be to use it, if there isn't a strong reason not to (e.g. speed). Avoiding lookups is just an implementation detail that the programmer normally shouldn't be concerned with.

Comment: @JohanL I don't disagree; you are right. But for a scenario where the usage of either one results in same result while the one has a slight advantage of speed and probably more readable (subjective), it takes a leap ahead. Yes, it's not in general as you say in your first comment. BTW, I just realised a flaw in my code.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use [counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and re for this

```
import re
from collections import Counter
remove_punctutation = re.findall("[A-Za-z]+",sent)
print(dict(Counter(remove_punctutation)))
#{'What': 1,'a': 1,'wonderful': 1,'day': 1,'Birds': 1,'are': 2,'singing': 1,'children': 1,'laughing': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

`collections.Counter` can be used to count occurences of anything in a list. That is a good start. That means, however that we should first make the sentence into a list of words and remove punctuation.

To make a list of the words, there is a method called `.split()` which will split the sentence on white spaces. And to remove punctuation, the methos `.strip()` is a good choice.

As you already hint at, we should also normalize the case. For this, it is better to use `.casefold()` rather than `.lower()`. In some locals these will not be identical.

All-in-all that leads to code looking somewhat like:

```
import string
from collections import Counter

sent = "What a wonderful day. Birds are singing, children are laughing."
words = [word.strip(string.punctuation).casefold() for word in sent.split()]
freq = Counter(words)
```